# How to programmatically create doctrees in Sphinx?

Tags: python, python-sphinx, restructuredtext, docutils

I'm creating a Sphinx extension that generates a pretty huge number of RST files.

Since I formally know the content of them, I'd like to gain time and space by directly writing the docutils, skipping the RST generation and parsing of them.

Is there a way to directly write doctree files and integrate them into my Sphinx documentation?

Comment: What does "directly writing the docutils" mean? What are "doctree files", as opposed to RST files?

Comment: RST is the writer-facing format for describing documents. They are first parsed into Docutils (and serialized to .doctree files) before rendered into a final format such as HTML.

Comment: I'm still confused. Are you referring to "doctree pickles"? https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/man/sphinx-build.html#cmdoption-sphinx-build-d

Comment: Yup, i'm talking about them.

Comment: AFAIK, a doctree is a Sphinx/Docutils data structure that represents the contents of an RST file. Are you asking if it is possible to generate HTML output directly, without having to read or write RST files on disk?

Comment: Not quite. DocUtils is an abstraction of your documents once they are parsed from RST. Or from any other input source given you have the associated parser. It's also a Python library for writing such DocUtils. My extension generates a pretty decent number of documents. I programmatically write the RST files for them and wonder how I can use Sphinx API to, instead, directly provide them in DocUtils instead of RST so that I gain build time by avoiding the read/parse RST step.

Comment: I don't think it's impossible to do what you want, but I am not sure that anyone is willing to write the Python code for that from scratch. Edit the question to clarify exactly what you want. Post some code that shows what you have tried so far and where you are stuck.

Comment: I'll try to spend more time on this. I don't have anything more to add to the question though, tbh. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what i'm looking for: https://github.com/sphinx-doc/sphinx/issues/1139.
It's not a working feature for the moment.